# XMLHttpRequest POST in Laravel CORS Issue

Tags: laravel, api, post, xmlhttprequest, cors

I got a problem with XMLHttpRequest POST Method in Laravel, I have tried to apply several references such as [MyNotepaper](https://www.mynotepaper.com/easiest-way-to-allow-cors-in-laravel) and this link [laravel-cors-fruitcakes](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) but still didn't work.

This is to access online API data and is called on localhost.

This my stuck:

```
Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing
```

This my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://xxx.yyyy.com/api/update';
var params = "server=server&password=12345";
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
     }
};

xhr.send(params);
```

and for information with the post method, URL link, and the same params as in the code it works to display the data in Postman, I don't know which part I forgot.

this is my route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
```

and for middleware setting, I tried like in its URL Link reference.

from [MyNotepaper](https://www.mynotepaper.com/easiest-way-to-allow-cors-in-laravel) this is my middleware setting:

```
<?PHP

  namespace App\Http\Middleware;

  use Closure;

  class Cors
  {

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
     return $next($request)
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, 
     DELETE, OPTIONS')
     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Content-Type, 
     Authorization');
   }
  }
```

if anyone knows and can help me very happy and grateful for all

Comment: Did you add CORS middleware?

Comment: @tirtakeniten yaps, I have already done

Comment: Please put the CORS middleware setting to your question.

Comment: @tirtakeniten that's edited

Comment: what version of Laravel?

Comment: @lagbox Laravel 6

Comment: Your ajax call is to a `post` route but the route you shared is a get route with a view result

Comment: @apokryfos does it matter? isn't the function done in the XMLHttpRequest script section?

Comment: It does matter, there's no real indication here that the actual route you are calling does use the CORS middleware at all since you are only showing us the root route

Comment: hoo oke, so could you suggest how the route code @apokryfos?

Comment: Your route would be something like `Route::post('update', function () { return response()->json('Test data'); });` and this would be placed in `api.php`. Then you can press F12 and check the network tab to confirm whether the correct headers are attached to the response

Answer (score 0):

Put your middleware at the top of other middleware.

```php
<?php

// file: app/Http/Kernel.php

protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

I suggest you use middlware package from `barryvdh/laravel-cors`.

Comment: `barryvdh/laravel-cors` is `fruitcake/laravel-cors`

Comment: I am using laravel 6 and step by step from this references https://www.mynotepaper.com/easiest-way-to-allow-cors-in-laravel , and I did your suggest to 'Put your middleware at the top of other middleware.' but still didn't works

Comment: @lagbox I tried too from barryvdh/laravel-cors is fruitcake/laravel-cors, with really slowly focus, but still with stack error.

Comment: Maybe your web server by default not accepted cors. For example some shared host disable cors by default.